# Why are there mystery phantom keystrokes entered in Konversation's input box in GNOME 3.12 after heavy load and how do I fix it w/o restarting IRC?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, 14.10, irc

This is getting ridiculous. In 14.10, with GNOME 3.12 and Konversation 1.5-master #4303, I sometimes wind up in a situation where the system locks up for whatever reason (heavy load from other programs, usually) and Konversation comes back repeating previously entered keystrokes whenever I try to type, as if its input buffer isn't being cleared. I can control this somewhat by holding down keys; this changes what gets input and how. If I don't type anything, nothing happens; this only happens while I am typing.

Example: if I try to type `now is the time for all good men`, I get `nwi tial go`. due to random backspaces being the previous entered keybuffer entries. This is only one example, and not even an illustrative example at that.

I can fix it by restarting Konversation, but I'd rather not have to pull up logs for recent conversations.

How can I fix this somehow? Is there a way I can clear a program's X11 input buffer, if that is the problem? (Googling that doesn't bring up **anything**; is there no such concept?). Or the Qt input buffer? Or something else?

Thanks.